# How to programmatically count the occurrence of regular expression as quickly as text editor

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2012

I have written a C# program that opens a particular directory. It then opens each file in that directory and counts every occurrence of the following regular expression @"^CLM". The program returns the regular expression count from each file and places that count into a separate cell in a spreadsheet. The code I am using is below:

```
List<string> linesPost = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(diPostFiles + curPostFile).ToList();
int y = 0;
for (int i = linesPost.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
     string pattern = @"^CLM";
     Match m = Regex.Match(linesPost[i], pattern);
     while (m.Success)
     {
         y++;
         break;
     }
     (xlRange.Cells[startRow + x, 3] as Excel.Range).Value2 = y;
}
```

This does the work, but it takes a long time. If I open a given file in Notepad++, for example, and put in the same regular expression then hit the count button, I get the result very quickly.

Is there a more efficient way to count the instances of the regular expression? I am anticipating roughly 5,000 occurrence per text file. Overall size of each text file is roughly 5 MB.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is hard to tell what the bottle neck is in your code, but quick question, why aren't you utilizing Regex.Matches? Example use here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, you do not need any regex. You are just checking if each line starts with `CLM`.

Instead of

```
string pattern = @"^CLM";
Match m = Regex.Match(linesPost[i], pattern);
while (m.Success)
{
   y++;
   break;
}
```

You may just use

```
if (linesPost[i].StartsWith("CLM"))
    y++;
```

If you assign `CLM` variable, try assigning it before the loop *if it does not change until the loop end*.

Also, you have a line referring to early binding with Excel interop. I suggest using late binding or `dynamic` types to work with Excel objects, and do it **after the loop**. Right now, you access it in the loop, and it might take a lot of time. Add a `List<string>` variable before the loop, collect the values, and then insert into Excel after they are all collected.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Kind of new to C#, But this is really helpful!!! Not sure what you mean about early vs late binding and dynamic types, but will do my homework. Thanks Again!

Comment: Early binding will do for the time being. The most important thing is to fill the Excel sheet after you collect all the values you need, and paste the array to a specified Range in one go. I believe the performance problem you have is more with Excel, not with Regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you want speed, read in the entire file into a string variable.
Then run the regex on it, something like below.

This is the fastest way this can be done for 2 reasons.
1. The lines are continuous, not split into an array.
2. Regex engine code stays in the lowest level until it finds a match.
  (i.e. it will return a match possibly hundreds of lines apart from the last one)

*note* - You did say speed. If you don't want speed, then don't use this way.

```
int y = 0;
string allLines = @"read the whole file into 'string'";
Regex RxCounter = new Regex(@"(?m)^CLM");    // Unsing (?m) multi-line modifier option, inline.
                                             // If Dot-Net does not recognise this inline option
                                             // set it in the options field of the constructor.
Match _m = RxCounter.Match( allLines );
while (_m.Success)
{
    y++;
    (xlRange.Cells[startRow + x, 3] as Excel.Range).Value2 = y;
    _m = _m.NextMatch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the Regex outside of the loop (`var r = new Regex(pattern, ...)`) and just apply it inside (`r.Match(...)`)... this alone should give you some speed-up, because it does not need to be compile over and over again.